# ajax stop when spacebar enter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a weird situation.
my page as below:

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
$("#mydiv").load("showlist.php?q="+this.value);
});
</script>
<input><br>
<div id="mydiv">ajax content appear in here</div>
</html>
```

my showlist.php as simple as:

```
echo $_GET['q'];
```

The page runs fine when I enter i.e: **abcde** in the text box {it means the content in the mydiv tag replaced by what output by showlist.php }.
BUT when I type **abcd efgh** {it means it has ONE space in the string } then nothing appear within the div. It is just blank!
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should encode the string before passing it to the server using `encodeURIComponent()`:

`$("#mydiv").load("showlist.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(this.value));`

Edit: [A useful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) concerning `encodeURIComponent()` vs `encodeURI()`

Answer (score 0):

The ' ' (space) needs to be urlencoded to %20 (a '+' will also do)

Encode your URI's with:

```
var newUri = 'showlist.php?' + encodeURI("q="+this.value);
$("#mydiv").load(newUri);
```